# How to transfer images via Bluetooth (LE) to a desktop application

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are currently trying to implement the transmission of images from a mobile device (in this case an IPhone) to a desktop application. We tried already the [Bluetooth Serial plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial) which works fine for Android but does not list any devices when scanning for our desktop application.

To cover iOS support (AFAIK iOS only supports BluetoothLE), we reimplemented our desktop application to use BluetoothLE and behave like a peripheral. Also we altered our Ionic application to use [BLE plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble).

Now BluetoothLE only supports the transmission of packages with the size of 20 Byte whilst our image is about 500kb big. So we could obviously split our image into chunks and transmit it with the following function (taken from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/don/ad3d6f444925c57d169baf54e262348f)):

```
function writeLargeData(buffer) {
    console.log('writeLargeData', buffer.byteLength, 'bytes in',MAX_DATA_SEND_SIZE, 'byte chunks.');
    var chunkCount = Math.ceil(buffer.byteLength / MAX_DATA_SEND_SIZE);
    var chunkTotal = chunkCount;
    var index = 0;
    var startTime = new Date();

    var transferComplete = function () {
        console.log("Transfer Complete");
    }

    var sendChunk = function () {
        if (!chunkCount) {
            transferComplete();
            return; // so we don't send an empty buffer
        }

        console.log('Sending data chunk', chunkCount + '.');

        var chunk = buffer.slice(index, index + MAX_DATA_SEND_SIZE);
        index += MAX_DATA_SEND_SIZE;
        chunkCount--;

        ble.write(
            device_id, 
            service_uuid, 
            characteristic_uuid, 
            chunk, 
            sendChunk,         // success callback - call sendChunk() (recursive)
            function(reason) { // error callback
                console.log('Write failed ' + reason);
            }
        )
    }
    // send the first chunk
    sendChunk();
}
```

Still this would mean for us that we would have to launch about **25k transmissions** which I assume will take a long time to complete. Now I wonder why is that the data transmission via Bluetooth is that handicapped.

Comment: You should look at using an L2Cap channel with BLE to transfer a large file, such as an image

Comment: You can get pretty high speed with BLE if you do it properly. See https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-5-speed-maximum-throughput/.

Comment: So native implementation with the help of Cordova is the way. Does somebody of you know whether any working BLE example for large data transmission for iOS or Android exists?

Comment: I started a bounty regarding this question

Comment: transmission of packages depends upon MTU. Are you exchange their MTU through Exchange MTU Request/Response ATT layer command?

Comment: @NullPointer this is what we are currently trying to achieve with https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central. The function requestMtu() is only implemented for Android though, which means that we have to implement it for iOS first ourselves.

Comment: Yes, till now u also used in android and I can send 512bytes in one go when sending data to chrome browser

Comment: I did a lot of work with BLE while Android still supported Nearby notifications, but I am curious about why you would want to do it this way. BLE is normally useful for very small packets that do not require acknowledgement or that they are received. If I remember correctly, Android and iOS have set packet size limits, so you would have to split an image up into several packets and try to stitch them together probably... which would be difficult sense delivery is not guaranteed unless the sender also receives BLE packets and gets a confirmation packet.

Is bluetooth an option?

Comment: @ThatCampbellKid I thought actually that iOS only supports BLE, because even the Ionic Bluetooth Serial Plugin has implemented on iOS side only BLE. Is there actually an interface for Bluetooth Serial in iOS? If you have further knowledge how to transfer images from iOS that way, this would also be a great help!

Comment: I will check into it @Entertain, but I would be surprised if iOS forces BLE due to the nature of how it works. I know they use Airdrop (Bluetooth and wifi) for a lot of transfers, but would assume it has normal Bluetooth functionality to work with headset and other devices... If I understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to try out L2CAP your could modify your Central desktop app somehow like this:

```
private let characteristicUUID = CBUUID(string: CBUUIDL2CAPPSMCharacteristicString)
...
```

Then advertize and publish a L2CAP channel:

```
let service = CBMutableService(type: peripheralUUID, primary: true)

let properties: CBCharacteristicProperties = [.read, .indicate]
let permissions: CBAttributePermissions = [.readable]

let characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: characteristicUUID, properties: properties, value: nil, permissions: permissions)
self.characteristic = characteristic
service.characteristics = [characteristic]

self.manager.add(service)
self.manager.publishL2CAPChannel(withEncryption: false)
let data = [CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : "Peripherial-42", CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [peripheralUUID]] as [String : Any]
self.manager.startAdvertising(data)
```

In your

```
func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, central: CBCentral, didSubscribeTo characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
```

respective your

```
func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didPublishL2CAPChannel PSM: CBL2CAPPSM, error: Error?) {
```

offer the PSM value (= kind of socket handle (UInt16), for Bluetooth stream connections):

```
let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: PSM) { Data($0) }
if let characteristic = self.characteristic {
    characteristic.value = data
    self.manager.updateValue(data, for: characteristic, onSubscribedCentrals: self.subscribedCentrals)
}
```

finally in

```
func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didOpen channel: CBL2CAPChannel?, error: Error?)
```

open an input stream:

```
channel.inputStream.delegate = self
channel.inputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: .default)
channel.inputStream.open()
```

where the delegate could look something like this:

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    switch eventCode {
    case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
        if let stream = aStream as? InputStream {
             ...
            //buffer is some UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>
            let read = stream.read(buffer, maxLength: capacity)
            print("\(read) bytes read")
        }
    case ...
}
```

**iOS app with Central Role**

Assuming you have something like that in your iOS code:

```
func sendImage(imageData: Data) {
    self.manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    self.imageData = imageData
    self.bytesToWrite = imageData.count
    NSLog("start")
}
```

then you can modify your peripheral on your iOS client to work with the L2Cap channel like this:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
...
    if let characteristicValue = characteristic.value {
        let psm = characteristicValue.withUnsafeBytes {
            $0.load(as: UInt16.self)
        }
        print("using psm \(psm) for l2cap channel!")
        peripheral.openL2CAPChannel(psm)
    }   
}
```

and as soon as you are notified of the opened channel, open the output stream on it:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didOpen channel: CBL2CAPChannel?, error: Error?) 
 ...
    channel.outputStream.delegate = self.streamDelegate
    channel.outputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: .default)
    channel.outputStream.open()
```

Your supplied stream delegate might look like this:

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    switch eventCode {
    case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
        if let stream = aStream as? OutputStream, let imageData = self.imageData {
            if self.bytesToWrite > 0 {
                let bytesWritten = imageData.withUnsafeBytes {
                    stream.write(
                        $0.advanced(by: totalBytes),
                        maxLength: self.bytesToWrite
                    )
                }
                self.bytesToWrite -= bytesWritten
                self.totalBytes += bytesWritten
                print("\(bytesWritten) bytes written, \(bytesToWrite) remain")
            } else {
                NSLog("finished")
            }
        }
    case ...
```

There is a cool WWDC video from 2017, *What's New in Core Bluetooth*, see here https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/712/

At around 14:45 it starts to discuss how L2Cap channels are working.

At 28:47, the *Get the Most out of Core Bluetooth* topic starts, in which performance-related things are discussed in detail. That's probably exactly what you're interested in.

Finally, at 37:59 you will see various possible throughputs in kbps.
Based on the data shown on the slide, the maximum possible speed with L2CAP + EDL (Extended Data Length) + 15ms interval is 394 kbps.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this [comment](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central/issues/567#issuecomment-387688764)

The following snippet is taken from there

```
ble.requestMtu(yourDeviceId, 512, () => {
  console.log('MTU Size ok.');
}, error => {
  console.log('MTU Size failed.');
});
```

It is suggesting that you need to request the Mtu after connection and then I think you can break your message into chunks of 512 bytes rather than 20 bytes.

They have done this for android specific [issue](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central/issues/567)

Comment: Unfortunately this function is not implemented for iOS

Answer (score 1):

First I should say that there are already tons of blog posts and Q&As on the exact same topic, so please read them first.

If you run iPhone 7, you have the LE Data Length Extension. The default MTU is also 185 bytes, which means you can send notifications or write without response commands with 182 bytes of payload. And please make sure you absolutely not use Write With Response or Indications since that will almost stall the transfer. When you run iOS in central mode you are restricted to 30 ms connection interval. Using a shorter connection interval can have benefits, so I would suggest you to run iOS in peripheral mode instead so you from the central side can set a connection interval of something short, say 12 ms. Since iPhone X and iPhone 8, you can also switch to the 2MBit/s PHY to get increased transfer speed. So to answer your actual question why BLE data transfer is handicapped: it's not, at least if you follow best practice.

You also haven't told anything about the system that runs your desktop application. If it supports 2 MBit/s PHY, LE Data Length Extension and a MTU of at least 185, then you should be happy and make sure your connections use all those features. If not, you should still get higher performance if you enable at least one of them.